# Error during installation using usb

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (beside Windows 8) on my VAIO laptop using USB stick.
After booting from the USB, this message is shown:

```
Btrfs loaded
xor: automatically using best checksumming function: pIII_sse
```

I like to try Ubuntu. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the image to disk again and try once more. Try a different port and usb drive to help rule out those as issues. Also please let us know of the method in which you are imaging the drive with the Ubuntu ISO.